# Why isn't innerHtml working for this javascript?

Tags: javascript

What am I doing wrong that the following isn't working:

```
<div id="devtest">test</div>

<script>
var myarray = ["a", "b", "c"];

var somediv = document.getElementById('#devtest')
for (i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) { 
 somediv.innerHtml += myarray[i] + "<br>";
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/avg5ffj0/1/

Comment: You haven't defined WHEN or HOW.

Comment: Keep your browser console open!

Comment: For one thing, when you use getElementById you don't want a "#".

Comment: `document.getElementById('devtest').innerHTML += myarray.join('<br>') + '<br>'` is shorter and probably faster. Note it is also `innerHTML` and not `innerHtml` and you should really declare `i` with `var`

Comment: @Xotic750: what is the benefit of declaring i with var?  Most examples don't do that.

Comment: Without it, you are polluting the global space unnecessarily.The scope of a variable declared with var is its current execution context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two mistakes `innerHTML` and `document.getElementById('devtest')` without `#` :

```
var myarray = ["a", "b", "c"];

var somediv = document.getElementById('devtest')
for (i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) { 
 somediv.innerHTML += myarray[i] + "<br>";
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/avg5ffj0/2/)

Comment: Nice!  Should also point out that innerHtml should be innerHTML.

Answer (score 2):

The "id" of your element is "devtest", not "#devtest".

Oh, also, it's `innerHTML` not `innerHtml`.

Comment: That doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @4thSpace it will make a significant difference, as the strings "devtest" and "#devtest" are not the same.

Comment: #devtest != devtest (This is not a querySelector.)

Answer (score 0):

The code should be :

test

```
<script>
var myarray = ["a", "b", "c"];

var somediv = document.getElementById('devtest')
for (i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) { 
 somediv.innerHtml += myarray[i] + "<br>";
}
</script>
```

getElementById  take's just the id of the element  (without any # symbol)